# Прекращение выполнения процедуры SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

В начале процедуры поставил проверку на кол-во записей. Если записей нет, то return. В итоге процедура продолжает крутиться, что не так? Пробовал разные варианты: begin return end, begin goth endp end и далее в таком же духе.

```sql
If(select count(*) from table1)=0
Begin
return -1
End
```

Comment: Код проверок вы конечно показать не готовы, видимо он слишком секретный? тогда и в правду не стоит, вдруг кто то сможет найти в нем ошибку.....

Comment: Без кода прямо в вопросе собственно и нечего обсуждать

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков добавил код в описание

Comment: @CrazyElf ,добавил код в описание

Comment: Простите кода хранимки я досих пор не вижу, вижу непонятно чего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё должно прекрасно работать. Вот проверил на "рыбе" подобной процедуры:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spReturnTest @InputValue INT 
AS
BEGIN   
    IF @InputValue < 0 
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END
    
    SELECT @InputValue AS Result
END

-- Вернёт набор данных
EXEC spReturnTest @InputValue = 1

-- Ничего не вернёт
EXEC spReturnTest @InputValue = -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить проверку до запуска процедуры.

```
if(select count(*) from table) > 0

Begin 
  exec…
End
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]